# SQL - Transpose one row into two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose

Mine SQL Query returns a few columns but only one row. I need to transpose this one row and column's names into two columns - first with column's names and second with row values. For some reasons I can't use crosstab.

Operation that I want to perform is shown below.
Before:

```
 Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
---------+---------+---------+--------
 Value1  | Value2  | Value3  | Value4
```

And I want to get this:

```
Cols    |   Vals
--------+---------
Column1 |  Value1
Column2 |  Value2
Column3 |  Value3
Column4 |  Value4
```

Comment: `UNION` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT 
    'Column1' AS Cols
    , Column1 AS Vals
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Column2' AS Cols
    , Column2 AS Vals
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Column3' AS Cols
    , Column3 AS Vals
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Column4' AS Cols
    , Column4 AS Vals
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Column1' as Cols, Column1 as Vals from YourTable
union all
select 'Column2', Column2 from YourTable
union all
select 'Column3', Column3 from YourTable
union all
select 'Column4', Column4 from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try crosstab from the tablefunc extension. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tablefunc.html

It should do exactly what you want.

You can install the extension like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```